# I want output database one row as an link of another row but failed

Tags: php, mysql

and i want to output them in a table
thanks if anyone can help me
i am learning php.

I am study to making a links management,which use php and mysql.
I will be thanks very much if someone can recommend the source code.

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("abc", $con);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='{$row[Link]}'>{$row[Name]}</a></td>" ;
    echo "</tr>";
    }


?>
```

Comment: we need more information? The code that declares $row where is it? can you post the whole script? or at least the portion that is relevant?

Comment: You need to escape nested quotes, otherwise they end as soon as the first match is found (your double-quotes will end after `href=`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes are all over the place, double quotes will be used to start and stop the string if you begin with them, but also you have quotes round the `<a>` tag, you can also omit the quotes round the index of an array if your inside double quotes, so you could use...

```
echo "<td><a href='{$row[Link]}'>{$row[Name]}</a></td>" ;
```

Or if you want to stick with double quotes, you need to escape the inner ones...

```
echo "<td><a href=\"{$row['Link']}\">{$row['Name']}</a></td>" ;
```